# jQuery.get() function not executing

Tags: ajax, jquery, get

I'm hijacking the click event and doing a $.get() on the href. Problem is, that the function that I'm defining doesn't get executed.

Firebug Console, shows that a GET request was actually made:

```
    GET http://localhost:8000/products/a-26-tavella-grip-168168-1a-3/ 200 OK 12ms
```

So, not sure what to make of this, the page is just a simple HTML page.

```
$(document).ready(
    function (){
    $("a.product_link").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        address = $(this).attr("href");
        $.get(address, function() {alert('get was performed.');});
    });
});
```

Any ideas why the function doesn't get called?

p.s. prior to this, the signature of the function included data, which I wanted to use, but 
console.log(data) returned as undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Firebug is the culprit here. Disabling it allows the code to execute.

Not sure why though, it's stealing focus of the Ajax call when it GETs back.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing your 2nd parameter as null

Comment: explicitly setting data to null changes nothing mate :(